# Combo Box Invalid Enties during Windows Restart

Tags: c++, mfc

This is an odd problem that I'm totally confused about. I've got two MFC VS 2008 programs that minimize to the system tray. They have configuration that includes Combo Boxes with data saved to a binary files that re-loads on startup of the app.

It has always worked really well. Recently we made a change to our "load with windows" to use a task scheduler startup (launch at logon) which, I admit,  *may be part of the issue*. I'm having trouble seeing how it would be though given what happens.

We've had a couple of customers with problems recently that after a Windows Update restart, the Combo Boxes are blank when the program starts up again. I've examined our config file and it has -1 in it. I haven't been able to sort out the timing of that change in the data just yet. The rest of the configuration is fine - just the Combo Box fields are messed up.

I have tried on three different computers (including one it happened on during a Windows update) to duplicate this; multiple restarts have failed to generate the problem. It seems specifically tied to a Windows-forced restart.

That makes me think it isn't the scheduled start-up, as I'd suspected, but that maybe the Windows Update restart is somehow invalidating the Combo Boxes before the app actually shuts down. And that when Windows initiates the restart it is somehow different than a Start / Restart process?

So, I'm wondering if anyone's got any ideas, observations, or advice. I'm definitely going to look at the code as I'm *not* handling QueryEndSession, which I'm thinking might help. I'm also going to make our configuration save not allow a -1 change to existing data. That should stop the bleeding.

But I'm trying to understand the mechanism behind this more clearly and whether or not something about the scheduled startup might be causing it too. Just in case I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Thanks for your patience in reading all this!

Comment: Possibly the combo boxes are getting destroyed before you read the value that you're saving into the config file. If your program is being closed upon logout, the UI elements may have been destroyed before you're app knows it is being closed.

Comment: Thanks @1201ProgramAlarm. Indeed, that seems to be what is going on. Tricky to duplicate but I'll have to go write some clever code to try to trap the situation. Thanks for your input!